# How to import millions of records from flat file to oracle table

Tags: oracle, bulkinsert

I need to load huge data (around 30 million of rows) from a dump file to oracle. If I use oracle data import utility it takes @5 hrs. to load these rows to oracle table (I am plainly inserting rows to table without any additional check). Is there any way to optimize the import process?

Comment: What exactly are you using and how?

Comment: Hi Kris,
I am using Toad, through its schema browser I am selecting a table and use data - import utility. In import wizard i select the dump file and map data to table column and proceed to data import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that "data import utility" you mentioned is, actually, SQL*Loader. Is it? If not, it should be :)

There are several things you could do, for example:

- if there are indexes and/or constraints on the target table, drop/disable them (and reverse the action afterwards)
- if you didn't specify different, a *conventional* path is being used - switch to *direct path* (using the "direct=true") - it might make a HUGE difference
- also, load data in *parallel* (specify "parallel=true"); it works only with direct path and it'll allow multiple loading sessions to work at the same time

There might be some other options, but - if you try any of these, you should see some improvement already.

Comment: Hi Littlefoot,
Thanks for your input, I tried SQL Loader option as you suggested (direct=true, parallel=true) and results are impressive. It's now importing my data in 4-5 mins.
Thank you so much, for the help :)